# Check if the log-cleaner of a Kafka broker is running or not

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a few brokers which take care of the data of a few applications. I have the log-cleaner for all the brokers enabled with `cleanup.policy` as delete. There was an issue a few weeks back where the log-cleaner stopped working in one of the brokers and this led complete disk usage, and it wasn't detectable.

I am looking for an efficient way to **check if the log-cleaner of a broker has stopped working**.

Firstly, I am using the **Kafka 1.0.2 version**.

As a simple method, I have tried looking into the logs of the log-cleaner, and when the log wouldn't update for a considerable amount of time meant the log-cleaner stopped working.

But some of the brokers' log-cleaner's log was not getting updated for some reason even though the log-cleaner was running(understood because the size of the log of the applications didn't keep increasing after a considerable amount of time).

I have tried playing around with a few configs `log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio`, `log.retention.check.interval.ms` etc. on why the log-cleaner's log was not getting updated, but I couldn't conclude on anything. **Any ideas on how to check if the log-cleaner is running or why the log-cleaner's log wouldn't log?**

TLDR;

Had some trouble as the log-cleaner of a Kafka broker stopped and couldn't detect it in time. Looking for an efficient method to check the termination of the log-cleaner.

Comment: We send the log cleaner logs to Splunk and count the number of events over regular time intervals. Elasticsearch could also work for the same purpose. If there are none, it's stopped